# How to fix TypeError: insert expected 2 arguments, got 1 in Python Flask?

Tags: python, flask

TypeError: insert expected 2 arguments, got 1

so, when i got objects in fuction get, and then i want that value in my dataUser,

ive old list (output) [{ 'username':'budi'},{ 'username':'jhon'}]
and i wanna old list to new list (dataUser)

```
dataUser = []
print(dataUser)
class users(Resource):
# Get data
def get(self):
    query = User.query.all()
    output = [
        {
            "username":data.username
        }
        for data in query
    ]
    response = {
        "code" : 200, 
        "msg"  : "Query data sukses",
        "data" : output
    }
    for item in output:
        print(item)
        dataUser.insert(item)
    return response['msg']
```

so  i can set up those value in Post

```
    def post(self):
    UsersUsername = request.form['username']
    UsersPassword = request.form['password']
    UsersConfPassword = request.form['confPassword']
    try:
        if(UsersPassword == UsersConfPassword | datauser.username != UsersUsername) : // <-- to this
            model = User(username=UsersUsername, password=UsersPassword)
            model.save()
            response = {
                "msg" : "Data berhasil dimasukan",
                "code": 200 
            }
            return response['msg']
    except:
            response = {
                "msg" : "Data Tidak Berhasil dimasukan dikarenakan username / password salah",
                "code": 400 
            }
            return response["msg"]
```

Comment: Check how insert works https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_list_insert.asp

Comment: Have you looked at [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#data-structures)?

Comment: i have looking documentation, and use insert(i, x)

Comment: i mean old list to new list,

Answer (score 0):

`insert` indeed takes two arguments - the index to insert to and the object to insert. If you just meant to add all the items to the `dataUser` list, you could use `append` instead:

```py
dataUser.append(item)
```

Comment: dataUser still empty, idk whats going on

Answer (score 0):

The issue here that you use `insert(index, value)` method that need two arguments follow doc:
ex from w3school

```
fruits = ['apple', 'banana', 'cherry']
fruits.insert(1, "orange")
```

please fix your code with this

```
dataUser.append(item)
```

it will work.

Comment: i have using split object in my code, so value of item is {'username':'budi'},  so i need that value in out of class as dataUser, but when i use dataUser.append(item) still empty

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a new value to a list, use `append` to add a new item to the end of the list

```py
dataUser = []
dataUser.append("first item")
```

`insert` adds the value at the given positions,

```py
...
dataUsers.insert(1, "second item")
# roughly equivalent to
dataUsers[1] = "second item"
```